# SpriteKit in screensaver can't find images

Tags: swift, macos, image, sprite-kit, screensaver

I am making a screensaver in Swift using SpriteKit.
While testing screensaver in app, all the textures load properly. As soon as I make .saver and load it in System Preferences, SpriteKit shows that images are not found.

I used `(imageNamed: "")`, so I tried using

```
var imageURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "gradient", withExtension: "png")
let imageGradient = NSImage(contentsOf: imageURL!)!
```

,but I got the same result.
SpriteKit can't access images when built into .saver file, but works perfectly when ran through the app.

I have included images in bundle, in assets, in Target's Copy Bundle Resources/Development Assets/Resource Tags.

You can clone the project from here: https://github.com/Nazar-Bibik/SavePortal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked into this project: https://github.com/leebradley/nyan-screensaver
And I found how to properly do it:

1. You need to put images into bundle, not xcassets ( put it with .swift files )
2. Instead of using image name use the following

```
let sourceBundle = Bundle(for: MainSwiftFile.self)
let imagePath = sourceBundle.path(forResource: "picture-name", ofType: "png")!
neededTextures = SKTexture(imageNamed: imagePath)
```

You need to provide the name of the .swift file with your principal class ( principle class in info.plist file ).
The rest is simple - forResource is a file name, ofType is a file extension and instead of passing usual name in imageNamed: you provide String of path to file.
"imagePath" is of a String type.